# How to mount my RFID reader as /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, udev

I've a USB RFID reader and main software I found on linux could use it through  `/dev/ttyUSB0` device

When I connected it on my laptop I can see it with `lsusb` command returning :

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID ffff:0035
```

or `sudo lsinput` returning :

```
/dev/input/event16
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0xffff
   product : 0x35
   version : 272
   name    : "Sycreader USB Reader"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0"
   uniq    : "08FF20150112"
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

I've already configured a rules in

```
more /etc/udev/rules.d/20-rwrfid.rules 
# Chinese RFID RW
ATTR{idVendor}=="ffff", ATTR{idProduct}=="0035", MODE="664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Have you tried to run `evtest /dev/input/event16` (or whatever number it gets when you plug it in) and to scan something with the reader? Do you see anything?

Answer (score 3):

The device is not presenting itself as an USB serial port device, so it won't get a `/dev/ttyUSB*` device. It is apparently presenting itself as an USB input device.

You won't be able to use `/dev/bus/usb/001/012` exactly like a `/dev/ttyUSB*` device: using those devices would require using [libusb](https://libusb.info/), [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) or Linux kernel's USB API directly.

Googling on "Sycreader USB Reader", I see that at least some Sycreader products pretend they are a USB input device.

[This Python script](https://github.com/balag3/RFID_reader) is claimed to work with some Sycreader devices: it might be adaptable to your device too.

Answer (score 1):

You can only mount block devices for file systems.

If you want to use it as /dev/ttyUSB0, you need a driver to present it as a serial device. If there was a driver for this device, it would load already.

The vendor id 0xffff is strange. Maybe your reader is compatible to another USB device. If so, you must find out which driver would work for your device and load that driver. In addition, you have to convince the driver to accept your device. The details on this depend on the driver.

**Edit:**

run

```
lsusb -d ffff:0035 -v
```

and look for the word "Class". that should tell you kind of driver may work for your USB device.

Comment: May be I didn't ask my question well. I should use this bus in my case : `/dev/bus/usb/001/012` or something like that

Comment: The word "mount" doesn't fit, the rest is clear. I added a paragraph about lsusb.